# How to Draw line at only 45 degree angle using CAShapeLayer in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, cashapelayer

I can draw line using CAShapeLayer but I am trying to draw a line only at 45 degrees angle.
line must be drawn at 45 degree angle otherwise it will remove from view ,how can I draw a line using CAShapeLayer,Please help.
Here is my code for drawing line :

```
- (void)handlePanGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
 static CGPoint origin;
 CGPoint location ;
 if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
  shapeLayer = [self createShapeLayer:gesture.view];
  origin = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
  UIView *tappedView = [gesture.view hitTest:origin withEvent:nil];
  UILabel *tempLabel = (UILabel *)tappedView;
  [valuesArray addObject:tempLabel];

  if(valuesArray)
  {
      [valuesArray removeAllObjects];
  }
  valuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
 }
 else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
 {
       path1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
       [path1 moveToPoint:origin];
       location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];
      [path1 addLineToPoint:location];
      shapeLayer.path = path1.CGPath;
}
}

- (CAShapeLayer *)createShapeLayer:(UIView *)view
{
shapeLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
shapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
shapeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound;
shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0;
[view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];//view.layer

return shapeLayer;
}
```

Comment: You seem to have the programming figured out. The rest is just basic math. A chance to repeat trigonometry (sine, cosine, tangent).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you just need to check that the angle between `location` and the `origin` is 45 degrees +/- epsilon. So your code could look like this :

```
// EPSILON represent the acceptable error in pixels
#define EPISLON 2

// ...

else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
    path1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path1 moveToPoint:origin];

    location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];

    // only add the line if the absolute different is acceptable (means less than EPSILON)
    CGFloat dx = (location.x - origin.x), dy = (location.y - origin.y);
    if (fabs(fabs(dx) - fabs(dy)) <= EPISLON) {
        [path1 addLineToPoint:location];
        shapeLayer.path = path1.CGPath;
    }
}
```